# how to add a custom binding with python readline module?

Tags: python, readline, key-bindings

I writing some kind of REPL using python3 readline module. I would like to bind M-h (alt+h) so that it opens the documentation of the current command being typed in a pager.

The module has a `readlinine.parse_and_bind()` function but I'm not sure it can be used to bind custom command (that I would implement in python).

Comment: You may use more advanced library than `readline` - [python-prompt-toolkit](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/building_prompts.html#adding-custom-key-bindings)

Comment: did you read documentation about `readlinine.parse_and_bind` ?

Comment: doc is unhelpful. `readline.parse_and_bind(string): Parse and execute single line of a readline init file.`